# Passing ros message field argument as reference

Tags: c++, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Here is a little code illustrating my issue :

```
void test2(bool &test)
{    
    return;
}
void test(std_msgs::Bool &bool_test)
{
    //TEST 1
    bool a_bool;
    test2(a_bool); //Ok

    //TEST 2
    a_bool = bool_test.data;
    test2(a_bool); //Ok

   //TEST 3
    bool_test.data = a_bool;
    test2(bool_test.data); //Not okay
    return;
}
```

I'm not able to compile something like this and I don't know how I can use a function taking as argument a reference of the same type of one field of a ros message.
The error is the following :

```
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘bool&’ from an rvalue of type ‘bool’
     test2(odom_test.data);
```

I'm a little bit confused about this `rvalue` in the error. I've looked into it and the definition is :

> rvalue is an expression that can only
> appear on the right hand side of an
> assignment

Why does `bool_test` is considered as `rvalue` ? If it was true I wouldn't be able to write `bool_test.data = a_bool;` in `TEST 3`.

I know that I could do like `TEST 2` and create a variable for each field of my message but I would like to understand why the `TEST 3` isn't compiling. Is it even possible ?

NB : I used `std_msgs::Bool` and a function with `bool` argument just as an example, it happens with other type messages too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306855/passing-ros-message-field-argument-as-reference/) by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3907 on 2018-10-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2018-10-26**:
I've deleted my answer as I misunderstood the issue. Seems like it might not be possible with std_msgs/Bool, but I'm not sure why. The issue can be made more succinctly:

```
std_msgs::Bool my_bool;
bool & ref_my_bool = my_bool.data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After some digging, it would appear that the underlying type of `std_msgs::Bool.data` is `uint8_t` ([source](http://docs.ros.org/electric/api/std_msgs/html/Bool_8h_source.html)).

This is why something like the following fails to compile:

```
std_msgs::Bool my_bool;
bool & ref_my_bool = my_bool.data;
```

Perhaps a workaround is to use `uint8_t` type explicitly:

```
std_msgs::Bool my_bool;
uint8_t & ref_my_bool = my_bool.data;
```

Or passing by reference to a function:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <std_msgs/Bool.h>

void data_by_ref(uint8_t &test)
{
    return;
}
void std_bool_by_ref(std_msgs::Bool &bool_test)
{
    data_by_ref(bool_test.data);
}

int main(void)
{
  std_msgs::Bool my_bool = std_msgs::Bool();
  std_bool_by_ref(my_bool);
  return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) with karma: 1870 on 2018-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-27**:
Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it's giving the **same** error, so yes `uint8_t` is the right type for `bool` but I would like to know if it's possible without using another variable and directly have a function correctly defined to accept a reference to `bool_test.data` as argument.

**Comment by [jacobperron](https://answers.ros.org/users/26373/jacobperron/) on 2018-10-29**:
I've updated my answer to contain a complete example of what I think you are asking. As long as the callback signature for the data member has type `uint8_t`, you shouldn't need another variable as described. Changing your example fails to compile because of "TEST 1".

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-10-30**:
Thank you that's exactly what I've been looking for ! (Sorry I just realised your previous answer worked too but I misread that you changed the argument in the function from `bool` to `uint8_t` which was the main issue)